# values arent being passed to intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gridview

Stack Trace

[Picture of stack trace here](http://i47.tinypic.com/33z3cxe.png)

Values aren't being passed to the other intent. Every time I try to start the activity with the intent in it, it crashes.

```
//This activity will retrieve and display the different rewards that are available.
public class RewardsActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rewards);
    
    //stores retrieves and stores the current gridview
    GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    
    //Instance of ImageAdapter class that will load the images into the gridview
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    
    //This function is used to set a listener on each item in the grid so that      when its clicked it will go to the other view.
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id)
        {
            Intent i = new   Intent(getApplicationContext(),RewardsViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        
    });
    
    

}
```

This new intent is being passed to, when it's passed here it is stored in a variable then used in a `ImageView` to load an image.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RewardsViewActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_view);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.finalImages[position]);
}

}
```

ImageAdapter.java
package org.android.pps;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/*This class will be used handle the loading of the image view that will display all the
images of the rewards. (this will be used along with RewardsActivity and rewards.xml)
 */
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //variable that will store the current context of the application
    private Context c;
    private Integer num = 6;
    private int[] rewards_num=new int[num];
    private Integer[] Images = new Integer[6];
    public Integer[] finalImages;
    
    
    
    //for loop will set the correct image to the array if its either activated or deactivated
    
    public Integer[] fillImageArray()
    {
        //Array that will be used to show the reward images
        
        Integer[] Activated ={
            R.drawable.rewards1,
            R.drawable.rewards2,
            R.drawable.rewards3,
            R.drawable.rewards4,
            R.drawable.rewards5,
            R.drawable.rewards6,
        };
        Integer[] Deactivated ={
                R.drawable.rewards1b,
                R.drawable.rewards2b,
                R.drawable.rewards3b,
                R.drawable.rewards4b,
                R.drawable.rewards5b,
                R.drawable.rewards6b,
            };
        
        
        //for loop that checks to see all the rewards that a particular users has to assign a particular image.
        for(int x = 0;x<rewards_num.length;x++)
        {
        
            for(int y = 0;y<6;y++)
            {
                if(rewards_num[x]==y)
                {
                    Images[x]=Activated[y];
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    Images[x]=Deactivated[y];
                }
            }
            }
        
        return Images;
        
    
    }
    
    
    //constructor with the context being passed.
    public ImageAdapter(Context m)
    {
        c = m;
        
    }

    public int getCount() {
        
        return 6;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        
        return Images[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    
    // The function View  create a new ImageView for each item that is being referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        finalImages = fillImageArray();
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(c);
        imageView.setImageResource(finalImages[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
        return imageView;
  
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please always post the stack trace when you have a crash.

Comment: Yes I was trying to post it but they said I dont have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: make sure you are registering your activity in manifest as <activity android:name=".RewardsViewActivity "  
        "  
        ></activity>

Comment: put ImageAdapter.java source code here

Comment: as the issue in line23 so either imageView is null or finalImages is null ..

Comment: @Simon I just added an image of the stack trace [link](http://oi47.tinypic.com/33z3cxe.jpg)

Comment: just remove some images from imageAdapter means try by using 2-3 images

Comment: Please provide full_view.xml code also here .........

Comment: FYI, the best way to include a logcat trace from Eclipse is to highlight the the appropriate line in the Logcat and press ctrl+c, then paste them into your question, lastly highlight the pasted logcat trace and press crtl+k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finalImages in noi initialized there .........

it is finalImages in the getview which is not get called in 2nd activity (RewardsViewActivity )...........

if possible move this line to constructor  finalImages = fillImageArray();

Comment: thank youuu soo much I have been trying to fix this error for hours :D